# Raycaster cannot get the correct mesh . Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting, interaction

I know this question has been asked I lot of times but I cannot understand how does raycasting work. I have a function creating country borders from a geo json file as well as the fill of the country which I want to be clicked. When clicked some information should be displayed about the clicked country.

```
var borders = new THREE.Group();
function createBorders(dataJSON) {

var SIZE_AMPLIFIER = 20;
var WIDTH = 2500 * SIZE_AMPLIFIER;


var projection = d3.geoTransverseMercator().rotate([-10, 0, 0]) //center meridian
  .center([10, 52])                                             //longitude, latitude
  .scale(WIDTH * 1.5 - 505);                                    //scale

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("#Map").append("svg");

svg.selectAll(".country")
  .data(dataJSON)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", ".country")
  .attr("d", path);

var svgMarkup = svg.node().outerHTML;
var loader = new SVGLoader();
var svgData = loader.parse(svgMarkup);

svgData.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
  var shapes = path.toShapes(true);

  shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {

    var geomSVG = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape, {
      depth: 50,
      bevelEnabled: false
    })

    //needed for click event!
    var materialSVG = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.8,
    });

    var meshSVG = new THREE.Mesh(geomSVG, materialSVG);
    this.borders.add(meshSVG);

    //create borders
    var borderMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, linewidth: 3 })
    var borderGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geomSVG, 15);
    var bordermesh = new THREE.LineSegments(borderGeometry, borderMaterial);

    this.borders.add(bordermesh);

  })

})

this.borders.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)
this.borders.position.z = -300;
this.borders.position.x = 16300;

this.borders.position.y = 0;

//get only meshes, no linesegments

var countryMeshes = [];
for(let m in this.borders.children){
  if(this.borders.children[m] instanceof THREE.Mesh){
    countryMeshes.push(this.borders.children[m])
  }
}

//add callback for each mesh

for(let c in countryMeshes){
  countryMeshes[c].callback = function(){console.log(dataJSON[c].properties.name_long)}

}

this.scene.add(this.state.borders);
svg.remove();

}
```

Then I make the raycasting function:

```
 var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

   function onMeshClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);


    raycaster.setFromCamera(vector, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.borders.children, true); 

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      intersects[0].object.callback();
    }

  }
```

and at the end I add an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('click', onMeshClick, false);
```

The callback works but not in the correct order. I have to click on another country or even outside the map to be able to call some of the countries.

Answer (score 2):

You're grouping your `LineSegments` together with your `Mesh`es. Maybe when clicking, it's capturing a line instead of the mesh, since the Raycaster has a precision threshold of 1 world unit when measuring lines, which might be too large. Think of it as ray-casting with a wide brush instead of a single pixel.

You have 2 options:

1. Group your country areas separately from its borders.

```
var areas = new THREE.Group();
var borders = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(areas);
scene.add(borders);

svgData.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    // ...
    areas.add(meshSVG);
    // ...
    borders.add(bordermesh);
})

// When raycasting, only test country areas, leaving borders out
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(areas, true);
```

2. Lower [the threshold of your raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.params) so borders don't take up as much space in the raycaster's eyes:
   `raycaster.params.Line.threshold = 0.1`

Comment: I am separating the meshes from the line segments at the end of the createBorders function. What is more, some countries can be clicked even outside the plane itself or even outside the renderer container (imagine there is other stuff like inputs and other kind of information). I tried with the threshold approach nonetheless, but unfortunately it did not seem to work.

Comment: I see you're creating a `countryMeshes` array, but that's not what you're using for raycasting. You're still using `intersectObjects(this.borders.children)`, which includes both `meshSVG` and `borderMesh` objects. But if neither of these options are working, then I'm sorry but I can't help you without a working demo.

Comment: Thank you for the help! At this point I think I have no other choice but to create a working fiddle.